# Password protect multiple pages with different passwords for each page

Tags: php, session

I am using a simple session login for a php page. I would like some of the pages to have one password and some of the pages to have another.

If I use the login.php, I can apply it to all pages that need this ONE password, but I would like to have different passwords for different pages...

Here is my login.php

```
<?php
//sha1() encrypted password - current: 'superman'
$password = '18c28604dd31094a8d69dae60f1bcd347f1afc5a';
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = false;
}

if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if (sha1($_POST['password']) == $password) {
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    } else {
        die ('Incorrect password');
    }
} 

if (!$_SESSION['loggedIn']): ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<style>
body{font-family:sans-serif;}
h1{color:red;font-size:24px;}
input{padding:5px;}
label,input{font-size:16px;}
.login{
width:420px;
margin:0 auto;  
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
  <body>
  <div class="login">
    <h1>You need to login to view this file.</h1>
    <form method="post">
      <p>
        <label for="password">Enter Password Below: </label>
        </p><p>
<input name="password" type="password" maxlength="10" autofocus></p>
      <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></p>
    </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<?php
exit();
endif;
?>
```

How do I add a second password REQUIRE(login.php) that takes a different login? Do I need a different ID of a sort or something for each page to make them unique?

Comment: I would suggest you reading up on Design Patterns, Factory pattern would be ideal for this kind of problem.

Comment: Have a session var with the list of pages that have been authenticated for a given user/session. If it's not there then put the login up instead.